# Node express error: "can not set header after they are sent"

Tags: node.js, express

I define a express route like this:

qiniuRoute.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const qiniu = require('../controllers/qiniuController')
  app.route('/upload')
    .post(qiniu.uploadFile);
}
```

qiniuController.js

```
function uploadFile(req, res) {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

    console.log('receive');

    console.log(files.file);
    const localFile = files.file.path;
    const config = new qiniu.conf.Config();
    const formUploader = new qiniu.form_up.FormUploader(config);
    const putExtra = new qiniu.form_up.PutExtra();
    const key = files.file.name;
    const uploadToken = renderUploadToken(req, res);

    // fileupload
    formUploader.putFile(uploadToken, key, localFile, putExtra, function (respErr,
      respBody, respInfo) {
      if (respErr) {
        throw respErr;
        res.json({
          error: respErr.error
        })
        return;
      }
      console.log(respInfo)
      if (respInfo.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(respBody);
        res.json(respBody)
      } else {
        console.log(respInfo.statusCode);
        console.log(respBody);
      }
    });
  });

};
```

But when I make a file upload request error occurs show that "can not set header after they are sent", it seems that I response to client more than one time but I already return in error handle. I also have another guess that cause my fileupload is async function which means I can't res.json in my callback?

Comment: What this method does const uploadToken = renderUploadToken(req, res);?

Comment: remove throw respErr;

Comment: renderUploadToken is function to render a token which require req.body.accessKey and secretKey and return a string token. This is not related to this error.

Comment: Thx guy, I use res.json in renderUploadToken which is make the error. How idiot am i.